# Why won't my laptop power its backlight?

Tags: laptop, backlight

I am trying to fix a p-6831fx Gateway laptop that won't power any backlights.

The display started to flicker before it went out. I connected the backlight to a desktop LCD monitor to see if the bulb was bad, and it burned it out. I ordered a new backlight bulb — a 375mm x 2.0mm model that looks just like the one that was in the LCD screen. The new bulb didn't work with the laptop at all, but it did work with the desktop LCD and a 14" laptop, so I know I got a good bulb. Next, I ordered another inverter board. The new inverter board and the new bulb together still do not work in the laptop.

What should I test next, before I order something else? I used a multimeter to test the input voltage to the inverter board from the motherboard and I got readings of 1.5 volts and 3.3 volts. One pin doesn't seem to be used, as I am getting nothing from it.

I have also been trying to find the lid switch on this laptop to make sure this isn't a backlight issue, as I know most laptops' backlights turn off when the lid is closed.